# How to integrate Magento with OpenERP v8 (Odoo)

Tags: python, magento, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

How to integrate the Maganto connector with OpenERP v8 (Odoo).

I am trying to install it but it raises the error below. I also tried it with the `addons` path.

```
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/service/server.py", line 792, in     load_server_wide_modules
   openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 357, in load_openerp_module
    getattr(sys.modules['openerp.addons.' + module_name], info['post_load'])()
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/http.py", line 1142, in wsgi_postload
   root = Root()
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/http.py", line 922, in __init__
   self.load_addons()
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/http.py", line 947, in load_addons
   m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 83, in load_module
   mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/__init__.py", line 6, in     <module>
import magento_model
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/magento_model.py", line 34, in <module>
  from .unit.backend_adapter import GenericAdapter
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  import import_synchronizer
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 26, in <module>
from openerp.addons.connector.queue.job import job
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/connector/queue/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
 import model
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/connector/queue/model.py", line 31, in <module>
 from .worker import WORKER_TIMEOUT
File "/home/atul/openerp-8/openerp/addons/connector/queue/worker.py", line 34, in <module>
 from openerp.osv.osv import PG_CONCURRENCY_ERRORS_TO_RETRY
ImportError: cannot import name PG_CONCURRENCY_ERRORS_TO_RETRY
```

Comment: What is the exact command you used to launch Odoo?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `--addons` parameter, e.g.

```
python openerp-server --addons-path=web/addons
```

or

```
python openerp-server --addons-path=addons
```

Comment: I have did it  but it's othet problem relate woth dependacy